# Using Opennebula as an IaaS: Running benchmark accross all nodes, possibe?

Tags: cloud, cloud-computing, benchmark, distributed-computing, opennebula

Our current situation:
We have one Opennebula cloud infrastructure consisting of a cluster controller and 6 cluster nodes configured and working. All Nodes run debian instances on top of a kvm hypervisor. We have done this as a part of a school project. Unfortunately the school has not given us any requirements regarding software that should run on the infrastructure.

We are now looking for a software which can run on top of that infrastructure to demonstrate the power of distributed computing. Is there any kind of benchmark available that will stress-test the cloud or any other kind of load testing software.

We couldn't come up with any idea how a program could directly leverage the cloud infrastructure. The opennebula documentation and wiki were of no help either.

Answer (score 0):

There don't seem to be many benchmarks to choose from. You may want to have a look at [the CloudSuite by EPFL](http://parsa.epfl.ch/cloudsuite/cloudsuite.html). It includes detailed information on how to setup and run benchmarks for Data Analytics, Data Serving, Media Streaming, Software Testing, Web Search and Web Serving for Cloud Environments.

There is also a benchmark called [CloudCMP](http://cloudcmp.net/) by researchers from Duke University and Microsoft Research. I haven't tried it, but it might be useful for you.